# Need help to class accusative

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am novice when it comes to learning Russian. It is difficult but fun. I need you input and expertise on две фразы. What is "в пять минyт" and "в два часa" in this case? Would it be correct to say that they are Accusative?

1. Встретимться oколо **Центрaльного телегрaфа** (G) в два часa.
2. Электричка отправляется в пять минyт **одиннадцатого** (G).

Comment: `Петь` is `to sing`. `Пять` (five) have to be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

два часа (singular genitive)

пять минут (plural genitive)

2,3,4: singular genitive, e.g. три яблока, четыре окна, две рыбы

5,6,... plural genitive, e.g. семь яблок, восемь окон, десять рыб

Answer (score 1):

the whole quantitative group (number+noun) in both cases is in accusative. But the noun itself is in singular genitive in the case of `два часа` and in plural genitive in the case of `пять минут`